# heroku node server won't run

Tags: html, node.js, autodesk-forge

Hi i made a forge viewer with nodeJS and run locally, when i try to deploy on heroku it return "cannot get" in the inspector it sends **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"**

index.js is my root when is type "npm start" it calls my index.html

```
    var path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const config = require('./config');
if (config.credentials.client_id == null || config.credentials.client_secret == null) {
    console.error('Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables.');
    return;
}

let app = express();
app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use('/api/forge/oauth', require('./routes/oauth'));
app.use('/api/forge/oss', require('./routes/oss'));
app.use('/api/forge/modelderivative', require('./routes/modelderivative'));
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
});
app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); });
```

config.js, here where i put my logging informations to autodeskforge

```
    // Autodesk Forge configuration
module.exports = {
    // Set environment variables or hard-code here
    credentials: {
        client_id: process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_ID || 'xxxxxx',
        client_secret: process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET || 'xxxxxx',
        callback_url: process.env.FORGE_CALLBACK_URL || 'https://nodeforge.herokuapp.com/api/forge/callback/oauth'
    },
    scopes: {
        // Required scopes for the server-side application
        internal: ['bucket:create', 'bucket:read', 'data:read', 'data:create', 'data:write'],
        // Required scope for the client-side viewer
        public: ['viewables:read']
    }
};
```

and here is my index.html in a "public" directory who run the JS files.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Autodesk Forge</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Common packages: jQuery, Bootstrap, jsTree -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
  <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v6.0" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v6.0"></script>
  <!-- this project files -->
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/ForgeTree.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ForgeViewer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row fill">
      <div class="col-sm-4 fill">
        <div class="panel panel-default fill">
          <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="tooltip">
            Buckets &amp; Objects
            <span id="refreshBuckets" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="cursor: pointer"></span>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" style="float: right" id="showFormCreateBucket" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createBucketModal">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> New bucket
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="appBuckets">
            tree here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 fill">
        <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form id="uploadFile" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="hiddenUploadField" type="file" name="theFile" style="visibility:hidden" />
  </form>
  <!-- Modal Create Bucket -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="createBucketModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cancel">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new bucket</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="newBucketKey" class="form-control"> For demonstration purposes, objects (files) are 
          NOT automatically translated. After you upload, right click on
          the object and select "Translate".
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createNewBucket">Go ahead, create the bucket</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: localhost:3000]

Comment: 1. Have you verified that all the files and folders are on the server in the same order as you have locally?

Comment: 2. Are there any error messages on the console when you ran your nodejs app?

Comment: i don't know how i can verify the folder, but if it's like github, i think all is on heroku respecting the paths, the nodejs app run locally without any error i'll send a pic

Comment: i edited the topic adding a pic of the app

Comment: Where do you render your index.html? Not clear from your index.js

Comment: (Example) app.get('/',function(req,res){
       
     res.sendFile('index.html');

});

Answer (score 0):

I see you are following the tutorial material, but it seems you have made changes that could be causing the issues you are experiencing.

First, there is no index.js file mentioned at all, what we use is a start.js file that initializes the node server and the time npm start gets called and heroku will call this command as well, if you check the package json file you will see npm start is calling node start.js.

Second, I see some mentioned of ejs and I don't think the tutorial has any mentioned of it, do you need or did some changes to the html template in order to use ejs?

Also, it is best practice to NEVER show your API keys, specially in a place like Stack Overflow where millions of developers will see it, I will recommend disabling those keys and create new ones to avoid other users to use your credits.

I will say check this section again http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/nodejs_2legged

We have deployed this tutorial many times to Heroku with no problem, and what usually fixes any issues is following along the instructions step by step like it was intended. You can always download the entire source of the project as well and compare it to yours.

Comment: Do you have your code hosted somewhere so I can take a look ?

Comment: I tested it locally and I dont see any problems with the Backnode project. Are you passing along the ENV Vars in the Heroku setup for the values of the Forge Client Id and Secret?